# Difference between Arduino mega Vs Arduino Uno

Tags: android, arduino, microcontroller

What should be the better choice to buy an Aruino board. My concept is from desktop output is given to android device through internet and its out is to Arduino board via USB cable and board gives out to run motors.

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: You can use **ANY** Arduinos, including the Nano. Make sure you have some **motor driver** OR use **servos** (the driver is on board).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major differences are things like number of pins and memory sizes. Here is a good list:
http://arduino.cc/en/Products.Compare

The Uno will run most programs you will need and are very compact. Go up further if you have more pins requirements.

I can't add below since it says the topic is closed:

If your motors are small and you are thinking of running them all or a few doctor from the pins instead of from outside supply you need to be aware of the current capacities
http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations

Sounds like the uno will be fine for you unless you need slightly more current.

The easiest way to add android support is over a Wi-Fi or a Bluetooth shield that you can quickly add to your uno.

Comment: I have some sensor, 4 Dc motors and all. Mega have more pins than Uno. I want to know why Mega is best or Uno is best choice for my big Robot.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. How to give input to board from Android device via USB? Any Idea please share. I'm very new to this. What are all the total needed things I need to analyze for my project.